# Can't find the custom message....ImportError: No module named wam_node.msg

Tags: custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have wasted my whole day figuring this thing out. I can rosrun both packages, but python just cant find that "wam_node" package. I have used c++ before to use the same message and it worked. I don't know what is wrong ?
Am I missing something ?

Any help/suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**Error when I run the package (rosrun hand_control grasp_with_biotac.py):**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rohit/catkin_ws/src/BMI-robot-arm-control/hand_control/src/grasp_with_biotac.py", line 12, in <module>
    from wam_node.msg import HandPosVel
ImportError: No module named wam_node.msg
```

**Python code for import:**

```
from std_msgs.msg import String
from biotac_sensors.msg import BioTacHand
from wam_node.msg import HandPosVel
```

**"rosmsg list | grep Hand"output:**

```
biotac_sensors/BioTacHand
wam_node/HandPos
wam_node/HandPosVel
```

**manifest.xml of hand_control package :**

```
<package>
  <description brief="hand_control">

     hand_control

  </description>
  <author>robot</author>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <review status="unreviewed" notes=""/>
  <url>http://ros.org/wiki/hand_control</url>
  <depend package="wam_node"/>
  <depend package="wam_msgs"/>
  <depend package="wam_srvs"/>
  <depend package="wam_control"/>

</package>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186975/can%27t-find-the-custom-message....importerror:-no-module-named-wam_node.msg/) by [rkitect](https://answers.ros.org/users/18960/rkitect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-07-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're mixing catkin and rosbuild packages somehow. This is generally not a good idea.

Your hand_control package is in a catkin workspace, but it has an old-style rosbuild manifest.

Is the wam_node package a catkin package or a rosbuild package?

If wam_node is a rosbuild pacakge, you can't depend on it or use it from a catkin package.

If your hand_control package and wam_node are both rosbuild packages, you'll need the old `import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('package')` line at the beginning of your python node in order to set up your python path correctly.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rkitect](https://answers.ros.org/users/18960/rkitect/) on 2014-07-19**:
Yeah, I do have packages all mixed up, so that can be a problem. But anyways, now I have built a new catkin package and replicated the messages from wam_node for this package and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Catkin can't find it because it doesn't know your catkin_ws/src/ environment exists. Try doing

cd catkin_ws
&& source devel/setup.bash

then re-run the code. It should now know about your created-from-source messages.

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2014-07-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rkitect](https://answers.ros.org/users/18960/rkitect/) on 2014-07-18**:
I have that in my .bashrc, I can rosrun wam_node and all other packages in catkin_ws , anyways I tried sourcing that file again but it still cant import the wam_node.msg.